# Error with run.sh in kaldi tidigits example, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, speech-recognition

I'm just setting up Kaldi for the first time and going through the tidigits example. However with run.sh, I get:

```
steps/make_mfcc.sh --cmd run.pl --mem 2G --nj 20 data/test exp/make_mfcc/test mfcc

utils/validate_data_dir.sh: Successfully validated data-directory data/test

steps/make_mfcc.sh: [info]: no segments file exists: assuming wav.scp indexed by utterance.

run.pl: 20 / 20 failed, log is in exp/make_mfcc/test/make_mfcc_test.*.log
```

Looking at the log files, I see the issue is:

```
bash: line 1: compute-mfcc-feats: command not found

bash: line 1: copy-feats: command not found
```

This seems to be a PATH issue, and looking at other forums online seems to confirm this. However I'm not sure how to resolve the PATH issue. I've traced that compute-mfcc-feats and copy-feats commands are called in make_mfcc.sh in the steps folder (supposedly a symlink to the wsj example). Please help!

Comment: From your question, I understand the the issues found in the log files are made by the `run.pl` which, I guess, is a **Perl** program. How sure are you this problem is not Perl related? Please, you should add the tag `perl` and show the contents of **run.pl** program. Where are launched the missing commands `compute-mfcc-feats` and `copy-feats` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path to executables is configured with `KALDI_ROOT` variable in Kaldi recipes in `path.sh` script inside the recipe, for example, inside tidigits it is `kaldi/egs/tidigits/s5/path.sh`. The path specified is relative, so you must run commands from `kaldi/egs/tidigits/s5` folder and not from other folder. There could be following problems

1. You didn't compile Kaldi and binary does not exist in
   kaldi/src/featbin
2. You moved the training folder from kaldi and
   you didn't update the `KALDI_ROOT` variable in `path.sh`
3. You run the command `run.sh` from some other folder, not from
   `kaldi/egs/tidigits/s5` folder.

Usually you simply need to check contents of `path.sh` and specify the proper kaldi root there.

Comment: Yes it seems that Kaldi is not compiling properly on my Mac. I was using Xcode 8.x and found that I needed to downgrade clang. Now I'm getting an error with "make[1]: *** [chain-kernels.o] Error 2" when running /src/make, but at least it's a step forward.